# FFMPEG: Add multiple audio files to the video. Previous audio muffled

Tags: ffmpeg

I added three audio files (one per time) to the silent video using this command:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i video1.mp4 -i audio1.mp3 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [1:a] adelay=10000|10000 [voice]; \
        [0:a][voice] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest [audio_out] \
        " \
    -map 0:v -map "[audio_out]" \
    -y output.mp4
```

Taken from [here](https://json2video.com/how-to/ffmpeg-course/ffmpeg-add-audio-to-video.html#:%7E:text=Combine%20two%20audio%20inputs%20into%20one%20video&text=So%20I%27m%20telling%20amix,into%20the%20final%20output%20video.)

The problem is that every time the audio file is added the previously added audio is muffled a bit. So, finally, the full audio track looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

I would also consider any other working approach.